# What is Mathematical equation for (x * a) XOR (x * b) XOR (x * c)?

Tags: boolean-algebra, computational-mathematics

**The question is**; how to calculate `(x * a) XOR (x *b) XOR (x *c)`?

**Definitions are**; x, a, b, c are all large hexadecimal numbers known by default.

**Solutions are**; to calculate x*a, x*b, x*c and then bitwise xor them. the problem for this solution is that bitwise operation is binary logic arithmetic operation and its way too slow for large numbers and you should convert any number to Binary base and not an option to do without computer, at least for solution I'm looking for.

**second solution** was provided in this [stackoverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385389/xor-using-mathematical-operators), were: `(a − b)²` or `a + b - ab(1 + a + b - ab)` that all are wrong and you can test them yourself.

**Now, My question is**; is there any mathematical equation for XOR rather than bitwise operations? I searched everywhere but I couldnt find any working example of such thing.

***A bit of understanding***: XOR is bitwise adding 2 or more numbers without including carry bit in calculations. This means all odd TRUE(1) numbers will result in TRUE(1), and others to FALSE(0).

Any help appreciated.

Comment: "not an option to do without computer". Most likely so. Why in the 21st century is it necessary to do that without computer?

Comment: XOR on hexademical numbers actually can be done by hand (e.g. `6ab978e9d6de89b800c73` $\oplus$ `039468b20cedeb982096a` = `692d105bda33622020519`). I notice I'm confused why you find _multiplication_ easy, in that case. Do you have some "free" way to multiply large numbers?

Comment: Clarifying the point from Abstraction's comment. Because $16=2^4$ you can bitwise XOR large hexadecimal numbers one "digit" at a time, and that is trivial by hand and faster than multiplication. You seem to be looking for some magic formula, but I seriously doubt there is anything, and, as already explained, XORring is ridiculously fast anyway.

Comment: @Abstraction I'm looking for mathematical equation for XOR.

Comment: you guys missed my question:
My question is; is there any mathematical equation for XOR rather than bitwise operations? not to see if multiplication is slower or bitwise xor is fast.

Comment: XOR (traditionally denoted as $\oplus$, code `\oplus` in TeX) already _is_ a well-known mathematical function. It's normally supported by any code library for long integer arithmetic. If you want to express it using a certain set of functions then you probably should specify what functions are included in your basis. For example, can one use "reminder function" in the expression? Can one use $N$ such that $N$ is guaranteed to exceed $\max(x, a, b, c)$? etc.

Comment: @Abstraction, a XOR b = a + b - ((a & b) << 1) . I'm looking for completing this equation by only 4 basic operands (+-*/). but as you can see in my example, (a & b) is still problem. I hope I could clarify my question.

Comment: What is not mathematical in @Abstraction's equation?

Comment: @KurtG. please read my previous comment.

Comment: I did. Even $a+b-((a\&b)<<1)$ is a mathematical operation. It is still very unclear why you came up with this post and why you impose restrictions that are not motivated.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to express $x \oplus y$ using only $\{+, -, *, /\}$ (the latter being integer division), then I suspect you won't like the answer:
$$x \oplus y = x+y-2*\sum_{k \in \mathbb{N}} (x/2^k - 2*x/2^{k+1})*(y/2^k - 2*y/2^{k+1})*2^k$$

The sum is over an infinite set but only finitely many summands are non-zero.

Can it be done "easier"? Probably not. Notice that if you could use only $\{+, -, *\}$ and no summation/multiplication over infinite sets then any expression would be a polynomial and any polynomial is monotonic for large enough $x, y$ while $x \oplus y$ is not.